# TensorFlow error: "logits and labels must be same size", warmspringwinds "tutorial"

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, image-segmentation

I'm currently following this  [tutorial](http://warmspringwinds.github.io/tensorflow/tf-slim/2016/12/18/image-segmentation-with-tensorflow-using-cnns-and-conditional-random-fields/) and after I did some changes because of the tensorflow update, I got this error:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[399360,2] labels_size=[409920,2]
>        [[Node: SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape_2, Reshape_3)]].

Can anyone help me with this one?

Changes in the code:

```
#Replaced concat_dim=2 with axis=2
combined_mask = tf.concat(axis=2, values=[bit_mask_class, bit_mask_background])

#Update the import of urllib2 to urllib3

#Replace tf.pack with tf.stack
upsampled_logits_shape = tf.stack([
downsampled_logits_shape[0],
downsampled_logits_shape[1] * upsample_factor,
downsampled_logits_shape[2] * upsample_factor,
downsampled_logits_shape[3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because the number of logits is `399360` while you are providing to the function with `409920` labels. The function `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` expects one label for each logit, and it crashes because you are providing more labels than logits.

As to why it happens, you should post the changes you made to the code.